# delete a row in tableview from a button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, detailview

I'm trying to make a method that deletes a mission in a tableview from a button in a detailview but I can't seem to figure out how I can solve the problem.

This is my method:

```
@IBAction func missionCompletedButton(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    missions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath])
}
```

The compiler says use of unresolved identifier indexpath

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is due to the fact that you are referencing a variable called 'indexPath', though that is not a parameter of your function, nor is it (apparently) a visible variable within the scope of that function.

If the index of the "mission" being completed is known (for example, if you are always completing the first "mission") you can do something like this:

```
let missionIndex = 0 //The first mission
missions.remove(at: missionIndex)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: missionIndex, section: 0)])
```

Otherwise you're going to need to use some other method to determine which mission index needs to be deleted.  This will largely depend on how you've designed your tableView cells, datasource, etc.  Show a lot more code if you still need help solving this.